# How (if at all) could rounding Decimals improve performance?

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark

I am curious when I am doing any sort of math on a a bunch of decimals in my Spark program does it make any difference to round numbers beforehand? For instance does:

3.000009481 * 10.90001001010

Calculate the same time as something like:

3.000 * 10.900

Does it differ for multiplication, division, and more advanced things like power and square root etc?

I am wondering because lets say its a fraction of a millisecond when you are doing it on millions of numbers does it make sense to round? Or will you always get the same calculation times with decimals?

I have a large aggregateByKey function that is doing a lot of computation. The cluster I am on consistently provides inconsistent performance metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can make a huge difference numerically (see: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)) but won't affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

Spark SQL's `Optimizer` uses `DecimalAggregates` logical optimization that replaces `Decimal`-based calculations with optimized operators when the precision is smaller than:

- 9 for `sum` aggregate function, e.g. `"SELECT sum(cast(id AS DECIMAL(5,0))) FROM range(1)"`
- 12 for `avg` aggregate function, e.g. `"SELECT avg(cast(id AS DECIMAL(10,0))) FROM range(1)"`

See [functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) object for `sum` and `avg`.

So, in case of structured queries in Spark SQL, it does make sense to round if you can (explicitly or by using a schema with correct types).